# How to add mean,minimum,max column for this given dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I was trying to add a new column **mean_dist** which is based on **sim_distance and Distance**

for example:for the first four rows in *sim_distance*,the *Distance* are different and want to get mean of those values in column(mean_distance)

Similarly i want to add new column like min_dist,max_dist,min_azi,max azi and standard deviation.

I tried to add mean as follows and it didn't worked:

`df2['Mean_dist'] = df2.groupby('Current_Sim_distance_r_obj1')['Distance'].mean()`

The sample data is as below:

| Cycle_Count | Sim_Azi | Sim_distance | Azimuth | Distance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 87417 | -55 | 3.38 | -55.85 | 4.38 |
| 87419 | -55 | 3.38 | -55.86 | 4.37 |
| 87419 | -55 | 3.38 | -55.86 | 4.37 |
| 87435 | -55 | 3.38 | -55.84 | 4.37 |
| 87441 | -55 | 7.92 | -55.84 | 7.47 |
| 87447 | -55 | 7.92 | -55.95 | 7.45 |
| 87459 | -55 | 7.92 | -55.86 | 7.78 |
| 87465 | -55 | 7.92 | -55.98 | 7.35 |
| 87471 | -45 | 7.38 | -45.84 | 7.37 |
| 87474 | -45 | 7.38 | -45.96 | 7.35 |
| 87984 | -45 | 7.38 | -40.86 | 7.95 |
| 87984 | -45 | 7.38 | -40.86 | 7.85 |
| 88026 | -45 | 8.58 | -40.87 | 8.86 |

Expected output:

| Cycle_Count | Sim_Azi | Sim_distance | Azimuth | Dist | Mean_dist |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 87417 | -55 | 3.38 | -55.85 | 4.38 | 4.37 |
| 87419 | -55 | 3.38 | -55.86 | 4.37 |  |
| 87419 | -55 | 3.38 | -55.86 | 4.37 |  |
| 87435 | -55 | 3.38 | -55.84 | 4.37 |  |
| 87441 | -55 | 7.92 | -55.84 | 7.47 | 7.51 |
| 87447 | -55 | 7.92 | -55.95 | 7.45 |  |
| 87459 | -55 | 7.92 | -55.86 | 7.78 |  |
| 87465 | -55 | 7.92 | -55.98 | 7.35 |  |
| 87471 | -45 | 7.38 | -45.84 | 7.37 | 7.63 |
| 87474 | -45 | 7.38 | -45.96 | 7.35 |  |
| 87984 | -45 | 7.38 | -40.86 | 7.95 |  |
| 87984 | -45 | 7.38 | -40.86 | 7.85 |  |
| 88026 | -45 | 8.58 | -40.87 | 8.86 |  |

I am not good at pandas.Could someone can help me?